# I was having issue with applyMiddleware in my react app

Tags: reactjs

import React from "react";

import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

import rootReducer from './components/store/reducers/rootReducer'

import {createStore,applyMiddleware,compose} from 'redux'

import{ Provider} from 'react-redux'

import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import {reduxFirestore,getFirestore} from 'redux-firestore'

import {reactReduxFirebase,getFirebase} from 'react-redux-firebase'

import fbConfig from './config/fbConfig'

const store = createStore(rootReducer,
// store enhancers
compose(
applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({getFirebase,getFirestore})),

```
    reduxFirestore(fbConfig),

    reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig),
)
```

);

ReactDOM.render(,document.getElementById("root"));

Comment: Fix your question's code by formatting it? Highlight the code and press ctrl + k. Also, please share what the current issue is. Are you getting a compiler error? Is it breaking when you are trying to start your server? Or is it a runtime error on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

it might be good if you added some detail or errors about what is actually happening in your application.  You are definitely going to get more useful hits if you provide more in-depth information.

At first glance it looks like your setup doesn't match the suggested setup for [thunks middleware](https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/integrations/thunks.html)

and that instead of passing your config to the store you pass it to reactRedux Firebase Provider

**createStore.js**

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import makeRootReducer from './reducers';

const fbConfig = {} // your firebase config
const middlewares = [
  thunk.withExtraArgument(getFirebase)
]
const store = createStore(
  makeRootReducer(),
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
  )
);
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/database'
import 'firebase/firestore' // make sure you add this for firestore
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import { createFirestoreInstance } from 'redux-firestore';
import Home from './Home'
import createStore from './createStore'
import { firebase as fbConfig, reduxFirebase as rfConfig } from './config'
import './App.css'

// Initialize Firebase instance
firebase.initializeApp(fbConfig)

const initialState = window && window.__INITIAL_STATE__ // set initial state here
const store = createStore(initialState)

export default () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider
      firebase={firebase}
      config={rfConfig}
      dispatch={store.dispatch}
      createFirestoreInstance={createFirestoreInstance}>
      <Home />
    </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
  </Provider>
)
```